# How to gross up an array of numbers so the sum of the array is 100

Tags: javascript

For example `[1,1] --> [50,50]` and `[1,2] --> [33.33, 66.67]`

Here is my code:

```
let total = getTotal(arrayOfNum);
let remainder =  100 - total;
arrayOfNum.map(n => {
  let newValue = n + ( (remainder / total ) * n);
 return newValue || 0;
});
```

This code does not gross up correctly when all the items in the array are `0`

`[0,0,0] --> [0,0,0]`
while I am expecting something like `[0,0,0] --> [33.33, 33.33, 33.33]`

Comment: where do you think the returned value `return newValue || 0;` is going? seriously, this code does nothing at all - so I doubt it only doesn't work in some cases ... it does exactly nothing

Comment: `var ratio = total/length; array.map(x=> ratio * x)`

Comment: what result do you expect for `[0, 0, 1]`?

Comment: So, only special case is - if all items are 0, right?

Comment: Why do you expect `[0,0,0] --> [33.33, 33.33, 33.33]`

Comment: @JaromandaX `return newValue || 0` is just to avoid NaN values

Comment: @NinaScholz I expect for`[0,0,1]` to get [0,0,100]

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes.

Comment: Lol. No. You do nothing inside map to change anything and throw away the array returned by map. As i already pointed out. The code you present in the question does nothing at all

Comment: But the solution is to check fit the edge case

Comment: @JaromandaX I know that I have to do something like 
`let x = arrayOfNum.map()...`
or `return arrayOfNum.map()...` if this code was inside another function. So you are right about I am throwing the array returned by map, my question was about the logic not the code grammar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you see this solution?

```
const t = [0,2];

const total = arrayOfNum.reduce((r,n)=>r+n);

arrayOfNum
          .map(n=> n/total)
          .map(n=> !isNaN(n) ? n * 100 : 1/arrayOfNum.length * 100 )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the array contains all zeroes, then take the length for getting the parts or take the sum for the parts.

```js
function getParts(array) {
    var sum = array.reduce((s, v) => s + v, 0);
    return sum
        ? array.map(v => 100 * v / sum)
        : array.map((_, __, a) => 100 / a.length);
}

console.log([[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 1]].map(getParts))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```